# How to vary the infoWindow size for different feature layers

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I have multiple feature layers on the map, and I wish to display a different sized infoWindow for each layer.

As far as I can tell, the map has one infoWindow, which can be resized using:

`map.infoWindow.resize(width,height)`

Each feature layer then provides the infoTemplate which contains the Title and Content, but no sizing information (right?).

How can I show a large infoWindow when clicking on FeatureLayer1, and a small infoWindow when clicking on FeatureLayer2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I think I figured it out.

Override the standard featureLayer onClick behaviour using:

```
dojo.connect(featureLayer1, "onClick", function () {
  map.infoWindow.resize(width1,height1)
});

dojo.connect(featureLayer2, "onClick", function () {
  map.infoWindow.resize(width2,height2)
});
```

Comment: That should do it! Good work Steve.